# Will my old Oly OM10 Mk1 support all the OIS features of my new Panasonic 14-140 Lens?

Tags: olympus, image-stabilization, panasonic

The Pano has "OIS" (optical image stabilization). It is a pretty new Lens while the Oly is about 8 or 10 years old. While the pictures look fine I can't tell for sure whether the in-camera stabilization or the lens stabilization is working as it should. Certainly there are no sounds (but I wouldn't expect that.) A lot of googling has not yielded a definitive answers. How would I confirm this. Or, how can I show for myself how wonderful my new lens' OIS is?

Comment: I don’t know for sure, but I believe you only get the in body stabilization. Otherwise the lens should work fine.

Comment: Amazingly neither Panasonic nor Olympus has a definitive answer!

Comment: I have an E-M1 Mk1 and it definitely doesn't support Panasonic's lens based IS. Regardless, I have a Panasonic zoom which works fine just with the in-body IS.